# How should I structure my Git repositories with my .NET Solution?

Tags: .net, git, branching-and-merging

I have a .NET solution that has, let's say, 10 projects within it.

There are a couple ways of thinking:

1. Use a Git repository per project, then use a repository for the solution and submodules. So, each `.csproj` file and dependent file gets its own repository.
2. Use a single Git repository for the entire solution. Everything the `.sln` file depends upon.

Looking at option #1, I think would be tough as if you are working on a feature branch, you have to create a feature branch for every referenced submodule. It creates a lot of overhead.

Option #2 seems easier to deal with branching, however, with a large number of developers on a project, you may run into quite a bit of merge conflicts, especially when dealing with the `.csproj` files.

How do other .NET developers manager their Git repositories with their various solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git repository should contain everything needed.  That is, cloning a respository should bring down everything needed to work with it.

That said, if the projects are self-contained enough to stand on their own; give them a repository of their own.  They can then be brought into the solution as either a submodule (if code is needed while working on the solution) or as a compiled dll (if just the functionality is needed).

Comment: This was ultimately how we structured our repositories. However, we did have a service project we put into a separate repository. The base n-tier application, even though different projects, is tracked through the same repository.

Answer (score 1):

We have all our stuff in a single repository that is set up like this

```
Main folder --> All solution files here
  -Sub Folder --> All executable projects
  -Sub Folder --> All library projects
  -Sub Folder --> All 3rd party DLLs
```

So if someone is changing a library project, every solution that references it is pointing to the same place.  And everything is together and organized, I suppose it causes a little extra overhead since you are always pulling down code you probably will never utilize, but I tend to like this approach.